# Rails + PostGIS errors migrating database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, geolocation, geospatial, postgis

I was following Daniel Azuma's talk on [geospatial analysis with rails](http://confreaks.com/videos/856-railsconf2012-getting-down-to-earth-geospatial-analysis-with-rails) but I am having difficulty whenever I run `rake db:migrate` in the second project.

The details of my setup are as follows: I am running Postgresql using [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/documentation) which gives me version 9.1.3 of Postgres and 2.0.0 of PostGIS. I run into a few issues with the database.yml file, and running migrations. ( I have added the relevant gems and required their info in application.rb)

My database.yml file looks like this:

```
 development:
   adapter: postgis
   postgis_extension: true
   host: localhost
   encoding: unicode
   database: my_app_development
   pool: 5
   username: my_app
   password:
```

If I add the following line `schema_search_path: "public,postgis"` I get:

```
 rake aborted!
 PG::Error: ERROR:  schema "postgis" does not exist
 : SET search_path TO public,postgis
```

If I remove that line I receive the following error when I try to migrate my database:

```
rake aborted!
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "geometry_columns" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='schema_mi...                       ^
: SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='schema_migrations'
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix these issues?

Comment: There is a migration included that references a polygon as a data type . However I don't believe there is an additional migration needed to be created for a geometry columns table I think it should reference the postgis adapter

Comment: Did you get a solution on this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how I solved the issue. I first created a new migration to add postgis to the database. (I have already installed both postgis and postgresql through homebrew on a mac.)

```
rails g migration add_postgis_to_database
```

In the migration file I removed the change method and used the execute method to add POSTGIS.

```
execute("CREATE EXTENSION postgis;")
```

After that you can check the database to make sure that postgis is available.

```
psql your_database_name
SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the migration file is supposed to look like:

class AddPostgisToDatabase < ActiveRecord::Migration
  execute("CREATE EXTENSION postgis;")
end

Comment: @will `rails g migration` will give you a template to add this code to, so put it inside the `change` block or write your own `up` method.

Comment: Chiming in late on this... @tomciopp I had used your solution on an application on my mac, and it solved the issue.  However on a newer application this CREATE EXTENSION migration is leading to the same error.  I conclude it must be some task upstream during installation that's missing..

Answer (score 18):

Drop PostGIS extenion in public schema and recreate it in postgis schema.

```
DROP EXTENSION PostGIS;

CREATE SCHEMA postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION PostGIS WITH SCHEMA postgis;
GRANT ALL ON postgis.geometry_columns TO PUBLIC;
GRANT ALL ON postgis.spatial_ref_sys TO PUBLIC
```

Comment: database.yml should also be amended to `schema_search_path: public, postgis`

Answer (score 3):

Actually,  the install command needs to invoke the postgis version

```
sudo apt-get install -y postgis postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
```

The simplest way forward is then to declare

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis" your-pg-database-name
```

avoiding migration hiccups.

Answer (score 2):

What version of PostgreSQL are you using? The `EXTENSION` thing [appeared in 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/release-9-1.html). Extensions are a handy way of loading several objects in one package.

If you're on less than 9.1 you'll probably be able to load PostGIS following [those instructions](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/postgis_installation.html#create_new_db) (all the `-f` commands). It may also be a good idea to upgrade, but that's up to you.

Comment: I am currently running 9.1.4 which I believe is the most current version of postgres.

Comment: Yes I found I needed to do it "the old way" like this even on pg 9.4. Not sure why the EXTENSION commands didn't fix the issue for me. I hit upon these instruction on the OpenStreetMap wiki which amount to the same thing (running these SQL files): http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PostGIS/Installation#Ubuntu_14.10.2B_2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, except while @Raido's solution fixed the issue for db:migrate, I was still having issues with the Apartment gem when a tenant was created (e.g. during db:seed).

I discovered that Rails was automagically adding `enable_extension "postgis"` to schema.rb, which Apartment uses to create the tenant schema. I'm not sure exactly why Apartment doesn't use the existing postgis extension (perhaps an issue with the search_path at the time of tenant creation), but this results in the same error.

The solution (if you can call it that) was to simply remove the `enable_extension "postgis"` line from schema.rb. The only problem with this approach is that any subsequent migrations which trigger a schema.rb refresh result in the line being re-added.

Also, I used the Apartment approach of adding the postgis extension to the shared_extensions schema instead of its own. My lib/tasks/db_extensions.rake looks like:

```
namespace :db do
  desc 'Also create shared_extensions Schema'
  task :extensions => :environment  do
    # Create Schema
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS shared_extensions;'
    # Enable Hstore
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS HSTORE SCHEMA shared_extensions;'
    # Enable uuid-ossp for uuid_generate_v1mc()
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" SCHEMA shared_extensions;'
    # Enable postgis extension for geographic data types
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS postgis;'
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis WITH SCHEMA shared_extensions;'
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA shared_extensions to PUBLIC;'
    puts 'Created extensions'
  end
end

Rake::Task["db:create"].enhance do
  Rake::Task["db:extensions"].invoke
end

Rake::Task["db:test:purge"].enhance do
  Rake::Task["db:extensions"].invoke
end
```

And my database.yml looks like:

```
postgis_options: &postgis_options
  adapter: postgis
  postgis_extension: postgis # default is postgis
  postgis_schema: shared_extensions # default is public

default: &default
  schema_search_path: 'public,shared_extensions'
  encoding: utf8
  <<: *postgis_options

...

production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'].try(:sub, /^postgres/, 'postgis') %>
```

Not ideal, but it's working. Perhaps this will save someone an hour or two with PostGIS and Apartment. I'd be interested to know if anyone has a better solution than removing the `enable_extension` call from schema.rb :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed this

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis
```

I was facing same issue due to missing this package.