# rails3, postgresql & postGIS: frozen in migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgis, postgresql-9.3

I found myself tangled up in testing various elements regarding postGIS. Had to backtrack... explosion!

I have tried

```
rake db:migrate VERSION=0
rake db:drop
dropdb development_db_name
```

and, even resorting to psql command line

```
DROP DATABASE v4_development;
DROP DATABASE v4_test;
```

with psql not listing any more those databases
I am constantly ending up with

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "geometry_columns" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='schema_mi...
                      ^
: SELECT * FROM geometry_columns WHERE f_table_name='schema_migrations'
```

(after deleting and recreating the database...)
I even attempted from within the postgresql command line the following

```
CREATE SCHEMA postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION PostGIS WITH SCHEMA postgis;
GRANT ALL ON postgis.geometry_columns TO PUBLIC;
GRANT ALL ON postgis.spatial_ref_sys TO PUBLIC;
```

no dice.  a pg_dump does indicate the extension is created

```
CREATE SCHEMA postgis;
ALTER SCHEMA postgis OWNER TO jerdvo;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS plpgsql WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;
COMMENT ON EXTENSION plpgsql IS 'PL/pgSQL procedural language';
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis WITH SCHEMA postgis;
COMMENT ON EXTENSION postgis IS 'PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions';
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE schema_migrations (
    version character varying(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Something deep has gone awry & I'd just as well start fresh. But I thought I had done that.
Other databases are not affected (have not checked all).

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190178/rails-postgis-errors-migrating-database

Comment: I'm afraid not.  I've been through those hoops a few times (one even solved an earlier problem)

Comment: to add a point the same error pops(-ped) up when migrating backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a long while to find the culprit.  Hopefully this can be helpful to anyone installing postGIS and who experiments leading to changes in migrations.

Fundamentally, to add a variable indexed via postGIS and postgre, as such:

```
add_column :structures, :lonlat, :point, :geographic => true
add_index  :structures, :lonlat, using: 'GIST'
```

an initialiser (UK spelling) needs to be invoked

```
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['adapter'] = 'postgis'
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

This initialiser has to be added to the initializer folder just prior to the migration that  **creates/destroys the first/last point column**. Otherwise the error pops up.

This is tested and functions in both forward and reverse migrations.
I can see where this solution gets messy with multiple installations in development mode.
 Any better solution welcome!