# Postgis existing project setup errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis

I'm having an issue setting up an existing project on my local computer.
I've already worked with postgres but it was behaving almost exactly like sqlite in rails and just needed to run the rake tasks to create and migrate my db. Never touched postgis before

This the error thrown onto me at rake create :

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  template database "template_postgis" does not exist
```

I had postgres and postgis installed with brew but deleted both since it seemed to cause another issue i had for some users so i'm now running Postgres.app instead.

I already tried to create it manually with dbcreate but then ran into :

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "geometry_columns" does not exist
```

I then tried all those solutions : [Rails + PostGIS errors migrating database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190178/rails-postgis-errors-migrating-database)

But when trying to migrate the add_postgis_to_database migration i'm still getting thrown that error.

I'm out of ressources now and would very much appreciate help.

PS: rails version is 3.2.8 , postges and postgis both last version(postgress.app version at least).